# How to remove border at the space where a upper button and lower panel are touching to make it look like merged?

Tags: css

I am making a filter button with a hidden panel. I have button as default. On clicking of button, a panel will show below button but in this view, i need a single border line which makes button as part of that and nor border where button is touching the below panel.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 20%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
  border-left-color: lightgrey;
  border-right-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: lightgrey;
  border-left-color: lightgrey;
  border-right-color: lightgrey;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question by providing us your code within a runnable snippet.

Comment: @chazsolo Can you please help me now?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do what you're asking but you can use a negative bottom margin to pull the button down by 1px so its white border overlaps the top border on the panel:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 20%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-bottom: -1px; /* add this rule */
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
  border-left-color: lightgrey;
  border-right-color: lightgrey;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-color: lightgrey;
  border-left-color: lightgrey;
  border-right-color: lightgrey;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```